# np.transpose behavior different for different array constructions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, transpose

I came across this weird behavior with `np.transpose` wherein it works differently when used on an `numpy` array and array constructed from a list. As an MWE following code is presented.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 5, (1, 2, 3))
print(a.shape)
# prints (1, 2, 3)
b = np.transpose(a, (0, 2, 1))
print(b.shape)
# prints (1, 3, 2), which is expected

# Constructing array from list of arrays
c = np.array([np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 3)), np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 3)), np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 3)), np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 3))])
print(c.shape)
# prints (4, 2, 3)
d = np.transpose(c, (2, 0, 1))
print(d.shape)
# prints (3, 4, 2), whereas I expect it to be (2, 3, 4)
```

I do not understand this behavior. Why is it that the array constructed from the list has the dimensions mixed up? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any unexpected behaviour in your example. `transpose` permutates the axes in the given order. Why do you think this depends on the construction of the array?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I was under the impression, the mapping worked the other way around. In the second example, 4 should have gone to the last dimension in the resulting array, 2 to the first and 3 to the second corresponding to `(2, 0, 1)`. But as pointed out in the answer below, the mapping is initially fixed and then permuted which I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.transpose()` picks the dimensions you specify in the order you specify.

In your first case, your array shape is `(1,2,3)` i.e. in `dimension->value` format, it is `0 -> 1`, `1 -> 2` and `2 -> 3`. In `np.transpose()`, you're requesting for the order `0,2,1` which is `1,3,2`.

In the second case, your array shape is `(4,2,3)` i.e. in `dimension->value` format, it is `0 -> 4`, `1 -> 2` and `2 -> 3`. In `np.transpose()`, you're requesting for the order `2,0,1` which is `3,4,2`.